# Create a file using fopen

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to create a file when a button is pressed on HTML page.
Button, when pressed, calls a php file that should do the job.
My issue is that no file is created but not error is received. The strange thing i noticed is if I call PHP file by CLI (for instance "php update_file.php") file is generated. What's is wrong?
Here is part of the code i'am using:

```
<form action="update_file.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> UPDATE </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


UPDATE_FILE.php

<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sets   = "SELECT grp_phone FROM groups WHERE grp_onoff='YES'ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sets)){
    $array = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        $array[] = $r[0];
        
   }

$group = fopen("/tmp/group_70000.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = 'SET Station_Group   "1": "1": "70000"
    {
    Attached_Stations = {".$array[0]"}
    }';
    fwrite($group, $txt);
    fclose($group);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Have you tried to store it in a different location than `/tmp/`? (Maybe there’s some automatic cleanup mechanism for the temp directory set up or something?)

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. The console user normally has read and write permissions in the FS while the web user has restricted access. Just for the test you might try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "1");` before calling `fopen()` and check if you see any warnings.

Comment: Hi, also tried to change folder. Same issue. By CLI it's ok. By "button" nothing happen.
Tried to put "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "1");" just before $group = fopen(...) but in console i can't see anything

Answer (score 1):

just to help someone else, issue was a permission.
I had to set as group owner of wanted folder as "www-data" and of course rw permisions.

/tmp folder has as group "root".

Regards